# What is it called when a person has to buy items to accomplish something else

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I know this woman who often says she doesnt have time to take her mom to doctors visits, or that there is money but she often takes trips to another city just for groceries and it is an all day trip.

She always has to have all the gadgets for her latest hobby. For example:

- baking cakes: she spends lots of money in all sorts of utensils, books,etc.
- exercise, she bought all sorts of exercise pants, tops, mats, balls, videos,especialty foods, paid dietitian, doufled bags, etc.
- preserves, bought all sorts of books,boxes and boxes of al types of ball glass jars, all sorts of equipment needed etc.
- making earrings, She got all sorts of items needed for it. What she uses are cut outs as the main item. She had the crukit and all the sortment needed.
- essential oils, She has to have all sorts of oils, enfussers, essential oil infused items, like tooth paste, drinks and foods. Also, gotta have the special storage, all this costing hundreds of dollars.

She also had to have a new Apple laptop. Even, when she has a desktop, laptop, ipad, apple watch, and a regular use Apple laptop. When asked about the purchases, She calls them an "investment". Oh and those items are used for a little bit, and then forgotten!

What is the word used for a person like this? A person that has to have something in order to accomplish something else?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! I *think* your question might be a word request (there's a tag for single word requests which can be used even if the term is strictly more than one word!) and these can be very popular. Usually the first thing that will be asked for is a sample sentence, something like "My friend has to have every gadget associated with her latest hobby. She is a ____!". Also, if you can, I'd suggest you itemise or list your examples because it's easier to read that way.

Comment: I've edited to make it a list. You can rewind the edits if you prefer. I haven't added the sample sentence, but I'm sure you can do that.

Comment: When you wrote “there is money”, did you mean to write the opposite? Otherwise, it’s normal for people with money to spend it according to their own wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps you, but among musicians, what this person displays is called [Gear Acquisition Syndrome](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/ambigamy/201110/gear-acquisition-syndrome-lustily-buying-more-tools-you-need), or GAS, for short. One could say she's GASing when she prepares to go on a shopping spree.

Answer (score -1):

"What is the word used for a person like this? A person that has to have something in order to accomplish something else?"

Some people might say they are **"a perfectionist"**.  I would say they're **"a maniac"**.

> - [**pefectionist**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/perfectionist) - noun - " a person who strives for or demands the highest standards of excellence in work,"
> - [**maniac**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maniac) - noun  -  "a person characterized by an inordinate or ungovernable enthusiasm for something"

In this case, it's a specific type of mania to describe a person who has an ungovernable enthusiasm for acquiring everything related to her job or activity.
It may or may not be a mental disorder.

Should their behavior result in personal distress, **"compulsive buyer"** may fit.